# Provisioning server with Puppet, deploying with Capistrano

Tags: apache, capistrano, puppet

I'm having issues with provisioning a server via Puppet that is compatible with a Capistrano deployment.  I'm using [puppetlabs/apache](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache) to setup my virtualhosts, and it is (rightfully) checking that the `docroot` exists (and creating it if it doesn't, ignoring potential nested directory issues).  However, the true `docroot` will be `/var/www/vhosts/${::fqdn}/current/public`, and Capistrano will be creating the appropriate symlink (from `current` to `releases/{releasestamp}`) when deploying, and is not happy when that directory path is setup by Puppet in advance (due to `current` being an actual directory, instead of a symlink, and not being empty).

I've thought about adding something like:

```
file { "/var/www/vhosts/${::fqdn}/current":
  ensure => 'link',
  target => '/tmp/initial'
}
```

and setting up a blank file at `/tmp/initial/public/index.html`, so that Capistrano will be able to point `current` to the appropriate release when deploying.  However, this means that whenever someone re-runs the provision (to apply any configuration changes, for example), the symlink will be relocated to the junk directory (if it even exists at that point).

Any suggestions?  I've considered splitting the provision into an application provision and server provision, and having Capistrano execute the application provision when deploying, but I'd really prefer to keep this concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use Puppet to create the application directory, and let Capistano take care of creating the `releases` and `shared` directories using the `cap deploy:setup` task, and laying down the `current` symlink when deploying a new version with `cap deploy`.

In more concrete terms, I recommend having this in your Puppet config:

```
file { "/var/www/vhosts/${::fqdn}":
  ensure => 'directory'
}
```

Then, as a one-time setup step, run this task to instruct Capistrano to create the `releases` and `shared` directories within the `/var/www/vhosts/${::fqdn}` directory Puppet should have created for you:

```
cap deploy:setup
```

And thereafter, simply run `cap deploy` to deploy your app, which will create or update the `current` symlink for you.

(Note that you can pass the `-n` option to `cap` to preview the exact commands Capistrano will run, For instance, `cap -n deploy:setup` will show the `mkdir` commands it runs.)

#### Updated

Puppet's standard [Apache](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache) module seems to require that `docroot` exist, which it does using the following:

```
# This ensures that the docroot exists
# But enables it to be specified across multiple vhost resources
if ! defined(File[$docroot]) {
  file { $docroot:
    ensure => directory,
    owner  => $docroot_owner,
    group  => $docroot_group,
  }
}
```

But you may be able to disable that using the following:

```
file { "/var/www/vhosts/${::fqdn}/current/public":
  ensure => directory,
  replace => false,  # don't replace the directory once Capistrano makes it a symlink
}
```

Just defining the resource yourself may prevent the `if ! defined(File[$docroot])` part of the `apache::vhost` module from running.

Comment: The issue with this is that the `apache::vhost` module has a `File` requirement for the document root, which means that the existence will be checked upon virtualhost configuration and created if it does not exist (assuming the parent directory exists ... otherwise, it's an error).  If I create the parent directory via your suggestion and set the document root as specified above in my example, I will get an error because `/var/www/vhosts/${::fqdn}/current/public` does not exist and cannot be created (as `/current` doesn't exist at that time).

Answer (score 1):

Stuart,

Thanks for the great answer.  I found that I had to amend it slightly to put the replace => false on the 'current' directory, not the 'current/public' directory, like so (using a vagrant owner):

```
file {
  '/home/vagrant/app/current':
    ensure => directory,
    replace => false,
    owner  => vagrant,
    group  => vagrant,
 }
```